# Get the authorization code from http://localhost in java application

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am working on an application where I have sync file to GDrive from my application, I have gone through the quickstart guide on Developer support. Also I am able to upload the file using the sample code. But I want to get the rid of that copy/paste of the authorization code returned by google. After reading some posts on stackoverflow I came to know about `redirect_uri` which I changes to `http://localhost` also am getting the auth code in the browser, but i don't know how to get it from the browser to my java application. Please guide me on how to get the auth code from local webserver to my java application.
Thanks in advance. And Merry Christmas to all the Developer friends.
Here's a code i have implemented.

```
public class CMDApp {

private static String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";

//private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
private static String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost/authCode";
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
    .setAccessType("online")
    .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));

System.out.println("  " + url);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String code = br.readLine();

GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

//Create a new authorized API client
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

//Insert a file  
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("My document");
body.setDescription("A test document");
body.setMimeType("text/plain");

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("D:\\Java GDrive Integration\\CMDApp\\src\\document.txt");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

}
}

I want to get the Auth code in this code from browser.

Comment: how are you getting auth code i mean in url or in response that sent by server?

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi: This is the url I get
http://localhost/?code=4/2qwq3I95Ygw0iTPBpk5cpTuMJmOb.YgGqBhjIc-sQMqTmHjyTFGOKKsE9hgI

Comment: What kind of a Java application is it? Desktop? Webpage?

Comment: @KumarBibek Desktop application.

Comment: Could you also add how you are invoking the browser? Is it on a WebView or you use the browser application? That would make the question more clear to everyone.

Comment: @KumarBibek:I have added the code I have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.getParameter("code") in your jsp file and set in your request object 
e.g.

```
<%
String authCode = request.getParameter("code");
request.setAttribute("authCode",authCode);
%>
```

and your server side you can get it

```
request.getAttribute("authCode");
```

Comment: I am not using jsp ! I am making a Desktop application.

Comment: are you using java.net.URL class to make a request?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are launching the default browser on the user's system, and asking them to login and finally copy and paste the code back into your application.

This way, you have no control over the browser application, and in no way can get the auth code automatically.

Try looking at integrating an inbuilt Browser window into your Java application by using a Webview.

You could use this if your application is a Swing application.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE

Once you integrate an in-app browser, you could easily capture the auth code when  the user finishes the login, then close the browser, and use that auth code in your application.

Comment: Actually later on I am going to call this application from within my MFC(c++) application with file path to be uploaded to GDrive. So its going to be command line argument. So is their anyway I can get the auth code with command line program in java. Also I want to download the file from GDrive using java. So if any tutorials you might be knowing please share the URL.